# Python for .NET - python lambda parameter in function definition called from C#

Tags: python, c#, .net, embed, python.net

I have the following code I want to convert to Python for .NET (so I want to embed Python in C#)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
x = np.array([4, 3, 2, 1])
y = np.array([1.43, 1.84, 1.36, 1.08])
model = lambda t, a, b: a * np.exp(-b * t)
params = curve_fit(model, x, y)
```

how to convert this to Python for .NET?

```
PythonEngine.Initialize();
using (Py.GIL())
{
    dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
    dynamic sp = Py.Import("scipy.optimize");
    var x = new List<double> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    var y = new List<double> { 1.43, 1.84, 1.36, 1.08 };
    var objective = (float t, float alpha, float kappa) => alpha * np.exp(-kappa * t);
    dynamic parameters = sp.curve_fit(objective, x, y)
}
```

objective however is not accepted, anyone got an idea, I prefer a solution without something like

```
scope.Import("numpy");
scope.Exec("model = lambda t, a, b: a * numpy.exp(-b * t)");
var model = scope.Eval("model");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it possible via C# functions, but you can use `PythonEngine.Eval` to create the lambda:

```
using (Py.GIL())
{
    dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
    dynamic sp1 = Py.Import("scipy.optimize");
    List<int> x = [4, 3, 2, 1];
    List<double> y = [1.43, 1.84, 1.36, 1.08];
    var globals = new PyDict();
    globals.SetItem("np", np);
    var objective = PythonEngine.Eval("lambda t, a, b: a * np.exp(-b * t)", globals);
    dynamic parameters = sp1.curve_fit(objective, x, y);
}
```

Note that `t` in the lambda is actually is `array_like` and the func returns `array_like` in the original code (`numpy.ndarray` if to be more precise).

Comment: Hmmzz ok ok so it is not possible to use c# lambda or anything for this?!

Comment: @BigChief I was not able to (I've created adapter lambda `PythonEngine.Eval("lambda f: lambda t, a, b: f(t, a, b))` but after that I've got bunch of type errors regarding input and output). And this seems to be by far the easiest option.

Comment: Ok is this the way of working with lamdas in Python for .net?! I also don't see it on the samples on their website

Comment: @BigChief it is not labmda per se, I was able to call it from python, but I can't figure out how to pass it to the `sp.curve_fit` (if it is at all possible)